# Shipping only to one city

Tags: shipment

I tried to find a solution on Google, but I could not find this specific question.
I am setting up Magento for a takeaway store that sells only in one city and I would like to know how to do that as by default you can restrict the list of the countries for the shipment but you cannot restrict the shipment to a single city. I am using Magento Community Edition 1.9

Thank you in advance for your help.

Regards,
Deviad

Comment: I don't have idea about code for this functionality but I can recommend you this [extension](http://www.magebright.com/shipping-filter-by-zip-code.html) which works good

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned there is a check for specific country. It is in `app/code/core/Mage/Shipping/Model/Carrier/Abstract.php` -> `public function checkAvailableShipCountries`. In it you can also add a check for city or postcode. At the beginning of this function you can add something like this:

```
if ($request->getDestCity() != 'somecity') { //or if ($request->getDestPostcode() != 'somepostcode') {
    return false;
}
```